# What is the basic definition of an amp-hour?

Tags: ampere-hour

What's the basic definition of an amp-hour? For example:

A 12V battery is rated at 100Ah.

Does this mean that the battery will be discharged in 1 hour if the load is 100A@12V?

Thanks.

Comment: 1 Ah = 1A * 1h = 1 [Coulomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb)/second * 3600 seconds = [3600 Coulombs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampere-hour). But that's probably not what you really wanted to know :)

Comment: Why was my post edited? I had it exactly like I wanted it. :/

Comment: What's wrong with the edit?

Comment: 12VDC@100A is now 100 A at 12 V. The additional spacing is not necessary, IMO.

Comment: @user94774 All of your most recent edits are wrong. "amp" is not a unit, "ampere" is. There are standards for how to write SI-units, which includes the space between the number and the unit. "@" is not an English word, in the same way as "u" is not a word.

Comment: According to the NIST guide (see here: http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/sp811.pdf ), you should use a space between a number and its unit (Section 7.2) and you may not abbreviate Amperes as Amps (Section 6.1.8).  "Ampere hour" (Section 9.2), "A h" (Section 6.1.5) and "Ah" (Section 6.1.5, Note 2) are all acceptable.  Also acceptable is if you seperate "A" and "h" with a half-high dot (Section 6.1.5).

Comment: What's a half-high dot?

Comment: A dot that is half way up the height of the font.  So A·h.

Answer (score 2):

1) the battery may not remain at 12 V during the whole discharge (and may start from over 12 V when fully charged). However (depending on the selection of the cut-off voltage (lowest voltage it discharges to), 12 V may be a reasonable value.

2) when discharged very quickly (and 1 hour is quick), most batteries tend to deliver less total charge. A more usual discharge rate (especially for claiming capacity) is C/10 -- a 10 hour discharge. This your battery may be expected to deliver 10 A for 10 h before falling to less than 12 V.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, you are correct.  But my gut feeling [in lieu of the datasheet for the battery] is that it's more likely that the battery will last for 100h at 1A discharge than 1h at 100A discharge.

The battery has a discharge current that it's rated at.  At that current, the battery has the capacity that it's rated for.  At the end of the discharge, the battery voltage will drop below a threshold voltage, and the battery is considered discharged.

Comment: The amp-hour rating traditionally was at a 20 hour rate, so at .05 C.  That's from the lead-acid days.  I don't know if they still do it this way for modern chemistries.